# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT

Tags: android, android-room

**I am trying to Insert a Book into Room:**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "books",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Account::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("user_id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("book_id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "book_id")
    val book_id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val user_id: Long = 0,
    val title: String = "",
    val note: String = ""
)
```

Not sure of why this issue is occurring at this very moment. This is a 1:1 relationship.

**Error:**

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY[787])
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:1127)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
```

Comment: make sure you firstly added entry in user table with "user_id" then try to add entries in book table

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that the **child column should be the user_id column** not the book_id; as per :-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "books",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Account::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("user_id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("user_id"), //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "book_id")
    val book_id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val user_id: Long = 0,
    val title: String = "",
    val note: String = ""
)
```

When you define a ForeignKey it is introducing a rule saying that the child column, *the `book_id` according to your code*, **MUST** be a value that matches a value in the parent column, *the `user_id` according to your code* of the parent table.

Of course when inserting a Book, then the Book MUST then have a value for the user_id field that is in fact an existing user_id.

With book_id column as the child column, which is probably generated then consider the following example:-

1. An Account is inserted and the user_id column is generated and is therefore, for the first Account 1.
2. The first Book is inserted the book_id is generated and is therefore most probably 1. As the Account has row who's user_id is 1 then the insert works.
3. A second Book is inserted the book_id is generated and is therefore most probably 2. As there is no Account row with a user_id of 2 then there will be a Foreign Key constraint conflict.

However with user_id as the child column then:-

1. An Account is inserted and the user_id column is generated and is therefore, for the first Account 1.
2. The first Book is inserted the book_id is generated and is therefore most probably 1. Assuming that the user_id column of the Book has been set to 1 (to indicate that the parent is the Account with a user_id of 1). Then the insert works.
3. A second Book is inserted the book_id is 2 and the user_id in the Book is 1 then the second Book is inserted as the user_id does in fact point/map/relate to the Account with a user_id of 1 (irrespective of the book_id of the book).

> This is a 1:1 relationship.

If it were a 1:1 relationship then an Account could only have a single book as a child, you might as well then embed the one and only book that the account could have into the Account.

What you in fact have is a 1:Many relationship (which caters for a 1:1 relationship). That is An Account can have many Books as children e.g. the walkthrough above, that uses the user_id as the child column, results in the single account have two Books as children (which I suspect is what you want).